# How to operate with values in the same column in .csv files

Tags: python, loops, csv

I've got a .csv file with different data formats and I'm trying to operate with the values on the same column.

My .csv file is something like this:

```
"int","float","string", more stuff...
```

Example

```
"7","1.378","rider 7",...
"9","1.979","rider 9"
"4","2.520","rider 4"
"2","4.711","rider 2"
More rows
```

And I would like to substract values in the 2nd column (only those ones, I don't care about the others). I manage to make the access and show values one by one, but my problem is, as I'm a beginner I don't figure out well how does the index deal with values and could save them to operate later.

The code I use is the following one

```
with open('file.csv','rb') as input:
csvin = csv.reader(input, delimiter=',')

for row in csvin:
    data = float(row[1])
    print "value -> %f " % data
```

With that I'd see

```
1.378
1.979
2.520
4.711
etc
```

But my objective is to obtain the result of substracting each value with the previous one

```
1.979 - 1.378
2.520 - 1.979
4.711 - 2.520
x - 4.711
etc
```

I would appreciate any help to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to do this:

- keep track of the last value and subtract
- store all values in a list and subtract element-by-element
- store everything in a numpy array and subtract shifted vectors

Which is best depends on what else you want to do.

For a concrete example, let's start with some data:

```
csvin = [[1, 6],
        [2, 14],
        [3, 1.1],
        [4, 3.14]]
```

If we run your code we see:

```
value -> 6.000000 
value -> 14.000000 
value -> 1.100000 
value -> 3.140000
```

So we know data is getting the values from the second column.

**Solution 1: Keep track of the last element**

```
last = None
for row in csvin:
    data = float(row[1])
    if last is not None:
        print "difference -> %f" % (data - last)
    last = data
```

Outputs:

```
difference -> 8.000000
difference -> -12.900000
difference -> 2.040000
```

**Solution 2: Use Python lists and subtract element by element**

```
all_data = [float(row[1]) for row in csvin]
print "differences: ", [next - curr for next, curr in zip(all_data[1:], all_data[: -1])]
```

Output:

```
differences:  [8.0, -12.9, 2.04]
```

Note: Here we construct both the list of all values and the list of differences with list comprehensions.

**Solution 3: NumPy**

```
import numpy
all_data = numpy.array([float(row[1]) for row in csvin])
print "differences: ", all_data[1:] - all_data[: -1]
```

Output:

```
differences:  [  8.   -12.9    2.04]
```

Note: This is slightly cleaner than solution 2 because it uses vector math. The result here is a numpy array as opposed to solution 2's list, but the individual elements of both may be accessed with the [] notation.

Comment: all_data[1:] is the data except for the first element, and all_data[:-1] is the data except for the last element, so they both have the same length, but are offset from each other by one.

Comment: Nice answer! Love all the different options. :) Now OP can explore NumPy for more numeric processing options or figure out how to make your `zip` example a generator for better performance.

Answer (score 1):

You're pretty close.

```
with open('file.csv', 'rb') as infile:
    csvin = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=',')

prev_val = 0
for row in csvin:
    data = float(row[1]) - prev_val
    print 'value -> %f ' % data
    prev_val = data
```

Answer (score 0):

The following script works for me...

```
prev_val = 0.0
with open('file.csv', 'r') as infile:
    csvin = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=',')
    for row in csvin:
        data = float(row[1]) - prev_val
        print('delta is', data)
        prev_val = float(row[1])
```